# I would like the ability to flag employers on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I just got my first offer through careers.stackoverflow.com.  The offer was for places other than the ones listed in my "Where do you want to work?".  This is one of my pet peeves.  There needs to be an easy way to flag employers as not following the rules.

Comment: +1: I got pinged as well from a couple states away :)

Comment: Did you set the "willing to relocate" flag and/or does the position allow telecommuting?

Comment: Wow, your day was ruined, ruined, because someone offered to talk to you about a job in the wrong place? Oh, the horror!

Comment: Was it Bozeman Montana and Boulder Colorado by any chance?  I got one of those too, and I've definitely checked the "Not willing to relocate" option.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin Why yes it was.

Comment: @bmargulies Ah, your day was ruined, ruined because I don't like wasting my time responding to idiot recruiters who can't read?

Comment: @bmarguiles - the whole point of *paying* for careers.so is because it's supposed to be better than the deluge of spam that any job seeker gets from recruiters who have harvested your email address and nothing else from your Monster and Dice profiles.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps for now you could just email the team. If this becomes rampant, that might be a different story.

Comment: Yeah, until it becomes a problem, don't program for corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

First, make *sure* you have not ticked the "willing to relocate" box in your profile

You can respond to employers now with actual text -- you might add a reminder in your response along the lines of "This job is a thousand miles away and I indicated in my profile I am not willing to relocate."

Beyond that, we'll look into it and make sure it's not a UI gaffe that caused employers to mess up.

Comment: Nope, it is not checked.

Comment: Jeff, it definitely wasn't checked in my case, and the text box comes up before you see the entire text of the ad.  In this case, they said "We're in Bozeman, but not all the jobs are in Bozeman, do you want to see them", and then you didn't find out that they meant one was in Boulder until it was too late.